# Theorem 1.1 in Bishop Goldberg paper on Gauss-Bonnet theorem in dim 4

Tags: riemannian-geometry

In *Bishop, R. L.; Goldberg, S. I.*, [**Some implications of the generalized Gauss-Bonnet theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1994158), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 112, 508-535 (1964). [ZBL0133.15101](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0133.15101). on page 513 it is stated

> In both Theorems 1.1 and 1.2, it is clear from the proof that $\chi(M) \neq 0$ unless $M$
> is locally flat.

where

> Theorem 1.1. A compact and oriented Riemannian manifold of dimension 4
> whose sectional curvatures are non-negative or nonpositive has non-negative
> Euler-Poincaré characteristic. If the sectional curvatures are always positive
> or always negative, the Euler-Poincaré characteristic is positive.

> Theorem 1.2. In order that a 4-dimensional compact and orientable manifold $M$ carry an Einstein metric, i.e., a Riemannian metric of constant Ricci
> or mean curvature $R$, it is necessary that its Euler-Poincaré characteristic be
> non-negative.

I do see how in Theorem 1.2 $\chi(M) = 0$ implies that $M$ is locally flat, but I don't see why it should be the same for Theorem 1.1.

The proof boils down to writing the Gauss-Bonnet integrand in dimension $4$ as presented in (4.1):

> $$\frac{1}{4\pi^2} [K_{12}K_{34} + K_{13}K_{24} + K_{14}K_{23} + R_{1234}^2 + R_{1324}^2 + R_{1423}^2] \omega \tag{4.1} $$

where $\omega$ is the Riemannian volume element and $K_{ij}$ is the sectional curvature of the plane generated by $\{e_i, e_j\}$, where $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$ is the orthonormal basis given in Corollary 4.1 that satisfies

> $$ R_{1213} = R_{1214} = R_{1223} = R_{1224} = R_{1314} = R_{1323} = 0\,. $$

If we take the sectional curvatures to be nonnegative, then all the terms in ($4.1$) are nonnegative. If we assume that $\chi(M) = 0$, then they all vanish. In order to have $M$ be locally flat, we should be able to get all the components of the Riemann tensor to be $0$.
However, $\chi(M) = 0$ only gives $5$ more zero independent components (I say that because $R_{1423}^2$ depends on $R_{1234}$ and $R_{1324}$). So why should the remaining $9$ be zero as well? ($9$ because in dim $4$ the Riemann tensor has $20$ independent components, brought down to $14$ by the frame).
The left components are

> $R_{1334}\,, R_{1424}\,, R_{1434}\,, R_{2324}\,, R_{2334}\,, R_{2434}$

and three between

> $K_{12} \text{ and } K_{34}\,, \quad K_{13} \text{ and } K_{24}\,, \quad K_{14} \text{ and } K_{23}\,.$

Am I missing something obvious?

In other books referring to these theorems, this extra information regarding Theorem 1.1 is not presented.

Comment: @Deane do you mean that the Gauss-Bonnet integral can be expressed as (4.1) in all orthonormal frames, or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: Apologies. I looked at the paper, and it is stating that (4.1) holds only for certain frames.

Comment: Good question. If you don't get an answer here, you should post it on MathOverflow.